# Newtonsoft JSON double converting JSON string

Tags: c#, json, string, serialization, json.net

I have something like the following:

```
class Data
{
  Foo foo;
  string s;
}
```

I need to serialize the Data object (let's call it "d") into a JSON string and I am doing something like:

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
```

It works perfectly fine.

And the string field "s" in Data is another JSON  string and not plain string. When Data gets serialized, the JSON string value "s" also gets serialized resulting in double conversion.

How do I annotate the string field so that the JSON serializer doesn't serialize it again?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, so I'll make a guess; You want to serialize Foo class as `{d:{fooooo}}`.

Then it is better if you use anonymous types

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { d = foo });
```

No need for `Data` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your field "s" with "[NonSerialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx)" attribute, that means your field "s" won't be serialized.